Maximal solution of ODE in Banach space
Context: Let $X$ be a Banach space and $U \subset X$ some open set. Moreover, let $J=(a,b)$ be some interval containing $0$ and let $Z \in C(J \times U , X)$ be a continuous vector field. Consider the following ODE:
\begin{align}
y'(t) = Z(t,y(t)) \ \text{with} \ y(0) = x \in U, \quad \text{or, equivalently,} \quad y(t) = x + \int_0^t Z(s,y(s)) ds.  \ \ (\dagger)
\end{align}
It is a well-known fact that under this setting of Banach-valued ODEs the solution need not to exist even for an infinitely smooth vector field. And, more surprisingly, assuming that we have a maximal solution $y$ over $(0,T_0) \subset J$, the solution $y(t)$ doesn't necessarily blow-up as $t \to T_0$.
However, according to Proposition 6.16 in here, we have the following:

Proposition: Let $Z \in C(J \times U, X)$ be a locally Lipschitz function in the second variable and $y : [0, T_0) \to U$ be the maximal solution to $(\dagger)$. If $T_0 < b$, then either $\limsup_{t\to T_0} \| Z(t,y(t)) \| = \infty$ or $y(T_0^-) := \lim_{t\to T_0} y(t)$ exists and $y(T_0^-) \notin U$.

Question: The idea of the proof of the proposition above is rather straightforward. However, I'm having issues with one specific passage and was hoping someone could shed some light on this. The proof goes as follows. Suppose $T_0 < b$ and $M := \limsup_{t\to T_0} \|Z(t,y(t))\| < \infty$. Then there exists $ T \in (0, T_0)$ such that $\| Z(t, y(t))\| \leq 2M$ for all $t \in (T, T_0)$. Hence, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$\|y(t) - y(t') \| \leq \left| \int_t^{t'} \|Z(s,y(s))\| ds \right| \leq 2M |t-t'|,$$
for all $t,t'\in (T,T_0)$. From this, the author concludes that $y(T_0^-)$ exists. I don't see why this is the case... From the estimate above we can conclude that $\lim_{t\to T_0}\|y(t)\| <\infty$. However, this doesn't imply the existence of $y(T_0^-)$, at least not in a generic Banach space. Am I missing something trivial?
Finally, if the proposition above holds, then by taking $U = X$ we immediately rule out the possibility of $y(T_0^-) \notin U$. Therefore, whenever $U=X$, a maximal solution over $[0,T_0)$ with $T_0 < b$ necessarily implies the explosion of the vector field. Am I thinking straight?

The Lipschitz condition implies Cauchyness. More explicitly, fix a sequence $t_n\to T_0$ from below. Then, $\{y(t_n)\}$ is Cauchy and hence converges; call it $\eta$. Now, for any $t\in (0,T_0)$ and $n\in\Bbb{N}$, we have
\begin{align}
\|y(t)-\eta\|\leq \|y(t)-y(t_n)\|+\|y(t_n)-\eta\|\leq 2M|t-t_n|+\|y(t_n)-\eta\|.
\end{align}
Taking the limit $n\to\infty$ shows $\|y(t)-\eta\|\leq 2M|t-T_0|$, so finally taking the limit $t\to T_0^-$ shows $y(t)\to \eta$.
And the second statement is right.

How did I miss this... xD of course the limit exists in $X$ which is Banach. Thank you for the clarification!
